# R AUC (metrumrg package) won't work

Tags: r

I've tried using the function like this:

```
AUC(WM,time=Grand.trial,id=Feed,dv=Distance.moved)
```

but it results in this error message:

```
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
object 'Feed' not found
```

I tried specifying the dataset for the object (WM$Feed instead of just Feed), but then I just get another error:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Can anyone help? Other ways to compute the AUC (trapezoid method) are just as welcome

Comment: Posting the output of `str(WM)` would be the _very_ least you could do towards providing sufficient information. Also, looking at `?AUC` suggests that maybe you should try passing the variable names as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using the `ROCR` package:

```
> library(ROCR)
> data(ROCR.simple)
> pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
> performance(pred, 'auc')@y.values
[[1]]
[1] 0.8341875
```

Comment: Thank you. I have read some documentation on the ROCR package, but I don't recognise the description as the kind of AUC that I am trying to compute (that's why I ended in the metrumrg package, though I couldn't find much help on that one). My x values are time points and my y values are weights, and the AUC should give me the area under the weight curve. Is that what I'll achive from your example?